# equals and hashCode Netbeans insert does not show up

Tags: java, netbeans, equals, hashcode

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

}
public int hashCode() {

}
```

Using Netbeans, I am trying to use the insert code functionality to create these methods.  However, when I open the menu, neither option is present, so I'm not exactly sure what I am doing wrong here.

I only have the option to insert constructor, logger, setter, toString, or override method.

Comment: `equals()` and `hashCode()` are methods of `Object`.  So you would want to choose to override the methods, not insert

Answer (score 0):

Since `equals()` and `hashCode()` are methods of `Object`, you want to override them.

So pick `Override method...`, then the following options (for `Object`) should show up:

- `clone()`
- `equals(Object obj)`
- `finalize()`
- `hashCode()`
- `toString()`

You can also just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in your class and you should see something like this:

[image]

Then you can just select `equals()` or `hashCode()`, which would generate the methods.

(works in Netbeans 7.3 at least)